# Rspec controller test with factory girl

Tags: rspec2, ruby-on-rails-3, factory-bot

I suspect I just being very dumb with this and missing something obvious.  But I fairly new to rspec and factory girl and cannot get this simple test to work.

Basically I have set up a model called page and am calling it in the controller like this:

```
@pages = Page.where(:page_type => "homepage").limit(2)
```

for in my test I do the following:

```
before do
     @pages = [Factory(:page), Factory(:page, :title=> "Contact", :content=>"contact content", :meta=>"meta content", :page_type=>'homepage') ]
     get 'index'
end

it 'should set the pages variable' do
   assigns[:pages].should_not be_nil
   assigns[:pages].length == 2;
end
```

yet all I get is:

```
Failure/Error: assigns[:pages].should_not be_nil
expected not nil, got nil
```

ANy help greatly appreciated

Comment: Shouldn't that be `before(:each) do`, or is that a typo?

Comment: Well it says you can do either in the rspec2 book, it's either a hang over from rspec1 or it just whether to run it before each test or not. Either way it didn't help, but thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your controller is setting its `@pages` instance variable to nil. Most likely it's not being assigned to at all. Are you sure the code snippet which you pasted:

```
@pages = Page.where(:page_type => "homepage").limit(2)
```

is being called in the `index` action of your controller? If so, that code would set `@pages` to the empty list, not nil.